# What are the effects of "Dump navigation cache" and "Dump V8 cache" in android debug mode?

Tags: android, webkit, mobile-webkit

I'm attempting to debug an issue on an Android device and have recently uncovered the browsers about:debug extra settings. There are, however, some options I am unclear about, such as the  "Dump navigation cache" and "Dump V8 cache" mentioned. I've spent a good bit of time searching for info but the only thing that I can find is the ability to change the User-Agent string.

Is there any documentation available on the about:debug method? Or could anyone enlighten me on what these dumps contain and where they are dumped to? The ability to view the browsers cache would be extremely useful to me right now ;)

Thanks for any help.